# Access command line --jobs parameter in Snakefile

Tags: snakemake

Is there a way to access the --jobs (or -j) parameter specified on the command line when running `snakemake` directly in the Snakefile without going through a parsing of the command line (sys.argv, argparse, etc...)?
One would think all command line parameters are stored in a python object accessible from within the Snakefile but I can't manage to find any documentation on that.
I am basically trying to retrieve the number of jobs given by the user to use a different parallelization system on a bottleneck script.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Currently not, but I understand your motivation. May I ask you to file an issue?

Comment: @JohannesKöster Sure I'll try as soon as I have two minutes. Thx for the nice job on sm !!

Comment: Related to this, I would find it useful if one could access other command line flags from within a script. 
Potential use case: Do or Don't redirect `stdout` to file based on whether the rule is run with `--debug` flag.